# Doubt regarding greatest lower bound property implies least upper bound property

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, real-numbers

**Least Upper Bound property** - A set $X$ is said to have this property if every non empty subset $A$ of $X$ which is bounded above has the least upper bound. (This does not imply the least upper bound must belong to $A$, which is my inference from the definition of least upper bound)

The definition for the **Greatest Lower Bound property** is analogous.

---

Let $X=(0,1]$ and hence $( X, \leq)$ is a partially ordered set where $\leq$ has the usual meaning.

Now clearly $X$ has the least upper bound property as its closed above.

> But if we take $A=X\subseteq X$ then what is the greatest lower bound of $A$?
>   How come then $X$ has the greatest lower bound property?

Comment: Do you mean $A = X = (0, 1]$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordered set $(X, \leq)$ has the *greatest lower bound property* if every non-empty subset of $X$ with a lower bound (*in* $X$) has a greatest lower bound (infimum) in $X$.

If we take $A = X = (0,1]$ then $A \subseteq X$ but there is no lower bound of $A$ in $X$ (note that $0 \notin X$), so $A$ is not a counter-example to the greatest lower bound property for $X = (0, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Abhay - You are welcome!